# Open Directory in Node.js and node-webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I have a function that should open a directory after it was created,

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    var fs = require('fs');
    console.log(newPath);
    var open = fs.opensync(newPath, 'r');
}, 2500);
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I am getting the following errors

first is,

> TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at eval (eval at `<anonymous>` (file:///Users/proslav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trackingCore-ecxfviftqracjxhimcuhhhvyddso/Build/Products/Debug/trackingCore.app/Contents/Resources/timeBroFront.app/Contents/Resources/app.nw/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:3:4994), :43:18)

and second is,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

I was thinking that it could be that my variable `newpath` is undefinded but the log shows me the right link. 
The creation of the directory with `var fs = require('fs');` works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks lime you have this in a client side JS file, you must have it in a server side file.

Comment: I'm stuck here a little bit. How would a server side JS-File look like in Node.js using node-webkit?

Comment: Look in the linked dupe answer, it should solve your case too.

Comment: Actually i found the right answer. Node-webkit has a function for it. I cannot post it because to question is marked as duplicate

Comment: hmm.. OK, you can now post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out how it has to be done. Node-webkit offers a function for that. It is working on MAC and should also work on windows. 
The function below is an example function. `nw.gui` and `gui.Shell.showItemInFolder` did the thing for me. Thx for the input.

```
/*---------
Open Folder
---------*/
function openFolder(path){
    var gui = require('nw.gui');
    gui.Shell.showItemInFolder(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In nw.js version 0.13 or later, use:

```
nw.Shell.showItemInFolder(fullpath);
```

Version < 0.13:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
gui.Shell.showItemInFolder(fullpath);
```

Note that the full path name is required. If it doesn't exist, it will fail silently.

If the path is something like **c:\foo\bar.txt**, it will open the folder **foo** and highlight the file **bar.txt**.

If the path is **c:\foo\foo2**, it will open the folder **foo** and highlight the folder **foo2** (I expected it to open the folder **foo2**, but it will open the parent).

---

To find the fullpath of the running app, as we can't use node functions in our front-end (that's why you had the error trying to load the fs module), I've created a node module (utils.js) with the following:

```
exports.getFullPath = function(fileName) {
    var path = require('path');
    return path.resolve(__dirname, fileName);
}
```

In the front-end:

```
function openFolder(path) {
    var utils = require('./utils');
    var fullpath = utils.getFullPath(path);
    nw.Shell.showItemInFolder(fullpath);
}
```